# kendoui getting started does not work - js has invalid token

Tags: kendo-ui

I am looking at KendoUI for a js app that will run in house. I download the kendoui (either opensource or the latest from them) and follow these very simple directions:

http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/introduction

Doing exactly as they suggest results in a js error of (same js error  if I run the files through a local apache server or directly as file:// in Google Chrome).

```
 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: missing /server/js/kendo.web.min.js:10
 Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'kendoDatePicker'
```

What gives?

The js files are found and loading. But it chrome complains about

```
 GET http://0.0.0.0:7773/server/js/jquery.min.map 404 (Not Found)
```

Perhaps these instructions are old?

Update:
It appears that the js files in the Kendo downloads are corrupt today. It works if I either link directly to the Kendo CDN, or if I download web.ui from github. Its not my zip expansion software (OS X 10.8), as the query 1.9.1 included in the kendo download works perfectly.

Comment: Some Progress. Replacing the js files I downloaded with the CDN versions fixes the issue...

Comment: I'm getting the same error.  Can you point me to the CDN version.

Comment: nvm I found what a CDN copy here: http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.2.716/js/kendo.web.min.js

Answer (score 0):

This is due to a [known](http://www.kendoui.com/forums/kendo-ui-framework/general-discussions/q2%2713-release---unable-to-get-property-jquery-of-undefined-or-null-reference-invalid-regular-expressions-or-expected-js-errors.aspx) issue. Long story short you need to download the bits again and use the updated JavaScript files.